# Verilog: When does a bufif1 gives out a write drive low?

Tags: verilog

I would like to know about how tri-state buffer works in the first place. Secondly, I had written a program to establish I2C protocol, while a READ condition, the slave yields a write drive low signal. I am stuck here and unable to solve the issue. Please help.

The slave which is a EEPROM has a tristate buffer (bufif1) in it.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know about how tri-state buffer works in the first place.

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic
2. http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/CompOrg/tristate.html

Other than that it is totally not clear what you have done so far, what seem to be a problem and how to help you. Consider providing a minimal working example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I am designing a I2C interface to connect I2c 64k serial EEPROM from Microchip to my controller. I programmed a simple I2C read code where in it performs a random read. I followed the procedures for making a random read in that eeprom through their manuals. The code works but at the end during the daya bytes transfer from slave to master, I could see only write drive low signals but not the actual data bits.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/e8lh21/6 - Here is the picture of the actual problem in the simulation

Comment: @san6086: Do you mark the port as inout? Consider providing a minimal RTL reproducing your problem, otherwise it is extremely hard to guess what could be wrong...

Comment: In your waveform viewer, is red = contention and blue = Hi-Z?

Comment: yeah blue is HiZ and red is a contention